# How do I generate a QR-code for a Monero address?

Tags: integrated-address, address

I would like to know if there's a tool to generate a QR-code image for a Monero address. I know that https://moneroaddress.org has a button to display the QR-code, but only for wallet addresses generated there.

Follow-up question, if possible, does this also work for integrated addresses?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

QR-codes have nothing specific to Monero. They are just a 2D representation of a string.

It should work with any qr-code tool, and for [any alphanumeric string of less than 4296 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code). So this includes monero public keys, private keys and integrated addresses.

For example on Linux :

1. Install packages : apt-get install qrencode zbar-tools
2. Generate a QR-code : qrencode -o addr.png "4A................."
3. Read the QR-code : zbarimg -D addr.png

There also plenty of websites that offers this service. However, please note that by using them, you may be giving up a bit on privacy.

Comment: Thanks, good remark about privacy with public websites. One follow-up though: when I scan a QR from the https://moneroaddress.org website, they are prefixed with `monero:`. Is this defined in a standard, or just custom to do so for crypto-currency addresses?

Comment: Not a standard. Qr-codes usually refers to [URLs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), which should start with a protocol identifier. So it's more a good practice that is not specific to crypto currencies

Comment: http://monero.wikia.com/wiki/URI_formatting

Comment: Came across a nice online QR-code generator: http://goqr.me. They claim not to cache the image for more than 30 seconds. Check their privacy page for details.

Comment: kudos for zbarimg as that's awesome.

Answer (score 5):

You can also go to https://duckduckgo.com, and type:

qr code 4xxxxxxxxxxxx

And it will show you a QR code for 4xxxxxxxxxxxxx. Replace that string whatever you want, Monero address or otherwise.

I recommend using monero:4xxxxxxxxx by the way, as this is the payment URI defined in http://monero.wikia.com/wiki/URI_formatting (and which is used by the GUI). Of course, if the receiver might be expecting a raw address, but hopefully not.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [**Monero Core GUI**](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core), for which a [beta](https://getmonero.org/2016/12/22/monero-core-gui-beta-released.html) was released on December 22nd 2016, it is also possible to display a QR-code on the "Receive" page:

[image]

It even allows to embed a payment ID, e.g. when scanned the above results in:

`monero:44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A?tx_payment_id=657c5df1563fd943`

Unfortunately the balance shown in the above screenshot isn't from my own wallet, just a watch-only wallet of the Monero Project's [donation address](https://getmonero.org/getting-started/donate/).